# How to get R data into a matlab matrix

Tags: r, matlab, matrix

I have a large data matrix in R. I used the package `'R.matlab'` to convert the data to matlab data like so:

```
writeMat(con="...filepath", x=data)
```

I have no experience with matlab so please be patient with me:

When I load the data into matlab it says I have a 1x1 struct.

I would like to get this into a matrix form. I tried:

```
data=struct2cell(x)
```

but that doesn't look quite right. The data is decimal valued numbers btw.

Comment: What is your data matrix class in R? Is it a numeric matrix or a data frame? Also what do you mean "doesn't look quite right"? What is exactly the problem?

Comment: Per posting guidelines, please provide a small, reproducible sample of your data, including info on `typeof` .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like your `data` variable in R is a data frame. Try first to convert it to a matrix before writing to mat file:

```
writeMat(con="...filepath", x=as.matrix(data))
```

Another way you may want is to convert the cell array to matrix in MATLAB:

```
datanum = cell2mat(data');
```

Comment: Thanks, it was because my data was a data.frame. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jupyter notebook. I think what you have to do is first install R.matlab library using

```
install.packages(c('R.matlab'), repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

Then implement this library using

```
library(R.matlab)
```

Afterward, you may have a dataframe in R say `resi`

```
#Save in Matlab v6 format with 'writeMat'
writeMat("resi.mat", labpcexport = resi)
```

I now go to Matlab and call it in that particular directory by the converting the struct to cell and then cell to matrix as

```
resi=cell2mat(struct2cell(load('resi.mat')))
```

I hope that helps